# How to connect to hadoop virtual machine of different computer?

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox

I had set up a two node hadoop cluster in same virtual box. Now I have to copy one slave machine to another computer that too in virtual box. How to connect master of one virtual box of one computer to slave of other virtual box of another computer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take A is master and B is slave in different systems.

Connect both systems under same network (same LAN or WLAN). Lets assume your A and B systems Ip address are 192.168.0.150 and 192.168.0.151

update both IP address in /etc/hosts, etc/hadoop/masters and etc/hadoop/slaves as well as update hostnames

Open terminal and ping other system, if you are getting replay, you are connected to other system successfully

connect other system by `ssh IP or hostname`

Comment: Thanks Krishna.Got an idea.